# Updating Data on a RPI hosted web page

Tags: web-server

I am working on project, requiring data to be sent from the on-vehicle system to a raspberry pi using GSM communication. The data will be accessed via a webpage.[image: Block Diagram]

I need the following data to be updated on the webpage
1.)Engine Status
2.)Actuator State
3.)Coordinates

The raw layout of the web page will be,
[image: Web Page]

The map will be a Google Maps API.

### Here is my questions

---

1.) How can I display the sent data on the webpage?
1.) How can I make sure that the data sent to the server(RPI), updates the webpage?
 I am a beginner at HTML & CSS, to perform the updation should I learn something else like PHP, SQL, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the data in a MySQL database on the RPI
Have the web page query the database for the data to display and use Javascript/Ajax to requery the database at suitable intervals to keep the data current. PHP, SQL and Javascript skills would be required but there are plenty of examples out there.

Answer (score 0):

if you want "live" updates then you'll need to look into websockets, these are the only way for the server to initial an action with a client (well the client connects first, but after that the server can push data as it arrives) there are a few libraries for different languages the support websockets, but last time i needed something like this i used nginx as a webserver (for the static content) and configured it to pass (proxy_pass) requests to `/api` to another process listening on another port.

the other process was written in python, when a new client connects it adds that client to the list, and when something happened (new data coming in) that updated data is pushed out through the websocket to all currently connected clients.

if you don't care about it being completely live then you could make it poll every few seconds to get the new data.